# How do I convert a currency (accuracy is secondary) from a static currency (say USD) for a web app (Django Framework)?

Tags: django, web-applications

I am writing a web app based on Django, and I hope to pick many of the good brains here on how I might be able to convert a price based on 1 static currency (say USD), to any other currencies?

Is there some feed or something I can parse to convert it on the fly?

Thanks.

Comment: You could try http://xurrency.com/api, I've no idea how good it is, but googling exchange rates api brought up a bunch of sites including that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a two (probably abandoned) Django apps to handle currency issues:

- [django-currencies](http://code.google.com/p/django-currencies/)
- [python-money](http://code.google.com/p/python-money/) (includes Django models)

Both of these projects include methods for doing currency conversions but will probably need some work before they are stable.

Then, you can update your table of exchange rates using a service like [XE.com](http://www.xe.com/).  If you're willing to pay for it you can update your rates every 60 seconds, but updating once a day is the cheapest.

As suggested by Ber and ozan, you can use cron or [django-chronograph](http://code.google.com/p/django-chronograph/) to schedule a script to run that does an HTTP GET to pull the data from XE, parses the data and then saves it into your models.

There are probably other services out there doing the same thing, so do some shopping before buying.

Comment: Just looked at xurrency.com linked by Dominic.  That looks simple (although SOAP is a pain in Python).  Their website doesn't mention how often the rates are updated though, which is weird.

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the party, but django-currencies isn't abandoned. Except from the auto-update the rates from a service it works swell. We already use it in a couple of our projects.

If somebody would like to help with adding syncing with a currency service let me know on the [app's page](http://code.google.com/p/django-currencies/) and I'd be happy to work along.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe reading an external source in the fly is detrimental to your application's latency, i.e. perceived user performance as you will depend on the source's availability and response time.

If real-time data is not required, you could have you own Model for exchange rate and update the data base table in the background every hour or day or so.

Comment: Yeah if it were me I'd set up a cron job to run on a regularity based on API allowances and the expected number of reads on that table.